# What does 'flat decision-making' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ****flat decision-making**** mean?

> The pure reason process advocated by Plato and Descartes is really
> more like the strategy patients with cortical prefrontal damage use to
> make decisions. Several forms of dementia plagued my father before he
> passed away. He had lost considerable access to his value system.
> Before advanced dementia, he always chose an O’Henry chocolate bar as
> a sweet treat. In the latter years, when I took him to a candy
> counter, he would scan the display for several minutes, reaching,
> hesitating, and finally choosing. He never chose an O’Henry bar, and
> the process seemed to take an eternity. I’m sure his final choice was
> based on giving up and taking the most appealing package within reach.
> It appeared that he lost the ability to make value-based decisions.
> When faced with a value-based choice between several competing
> selections, ***his decision-making landscape appeared hopelessly***
> ***flat***.

[Sudden Influence: How Spontaneous Events Shape Our Lives](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=mBxenLbLWE0C&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=O%E2%80%99Henry%20chocolate%20bar%20as%20a%20sweet%20treat.%20In%20the%20latter%20years,%20when%20I%20took%20him%20to%20a%20candy%20counter,%20he%20would%20scan%20the%20display%20for%20several%20minutes,%20reaching,%20hesitating,%20and%20finally%20choosing.%20He%20never%20chose%20an%20O%E2%80%99Henry%20bar,&source=bl&ots=10hVIn-1cJ&sig=ACfU3U1JbRjMnC8dp-_EWbxGaaMvZG0_JA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4m4Xk2OzwAhWHOZQKHbweDDEQ6AEwA3oECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=O%E2%80%99Henry%20chocolate%20bar%20as%20a%20sweet%20treat.%20In%20the%20latter%20years%2C%20when%20I%20took%20him%20to%20a%20candy%20counter%2C%20he%20would%20scan%20the%20display%20for%20several%20minutes%2C%20reaching%2C%20hesitating%2C%20and%20finally%20choosing.%20He%20never%20chose%20an%20O%E2%80%99Henry%20bar%2C&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't the decision-making that is flat, but the landscape. A flat landscape has no hills or valleys, that is, it is featureless. The dementia patient's prospect had no high or low features, no values; finally, he chooses based on the visual appeal of the packages.

Answer (score 1):

It was not his decision-making that was 'flat', but the metaphorical 'landscape' behind it. This isn't a standard expression. I suppose the author means that his father had no memories of his earlier preferences and habits to make the process of choosing interesting to him.